# How to list all entity content with other data without replication or missing data + UI display method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, linq-to-entities

I am still learning Asp.Net MVC. and I really appreciate any help!

**I have 2 questions:<**/br>

I have list of employee that the user wants to be displayed so he (the user) can select the employee for the added task

**Task==> Employee (M:M)**.

**Q1.** what is the best way to show this list of employee. I choose the grid with checkbox. but on second thought, I believe this list may go long and long (my guess is  about 50 names or more). and in case i must display a grid with paging.. for example. how can i tell that the user choose name#1 from page 1 when he goes to page 5.

**Q2.**
when the user edit the task and its employee. I want to display all of them (employee) with the selected emp for this task.
this solution sometimes works and sometimes not :\ and I don't Know why.

```
  public List<WorkerViewModel> GetAllWorkersForTheTask(int taskID)
    {
  var allWorker = (from w in context.Workers
                     select w).ToList();


    var list = (from x in context.WorkerForTasks
                join c in context.Workers on x.FK_WorkerD equals c.PK_WorkerID
                where x.FK_TaskID == taskID && x.FK_WorkerD == c.PK_WorkerID
                select new WorkerViewModel
                {
                    Worker = c,
                    isChecked = c.PK_WorkerID == x.FK_WorkerD ? true : false
                }).ToList();

    if (allWorker != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allWorker.Count; i++)
            {
                if (allWorker.Contains(list.ElementAt(j).Worker))
                    allWorker.Remove(allWorker.ElementAt(i));

            }
        }

        if (allWorker != null)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < allWorker.Count; i++)
            {
                 var worker = new WorkerViewModel() 
              { Worker = allWorker.ElementAt(i), isChecked = false };
                    list.Add(worker);
             }
        }

    }
        return list;

}
```

### **Edit **

**in Q1--> I want the user to be able to check All the itemes. (All and not just the inline editing for certain row). so in case Paging the grid - how can i tell which items is selected and which not ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using MVC Grid View. In my opinion it great solution to display your info. And also GridView has builtin pager and can be strongly typed.
This is a great article explaining MVC gridView : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430700/Html-GridView-in-MVC

it shows how to update your data throught the Grid.

Hope it was helpfull.

Comment: Thank you. But in fact the main point of the grid is to allow the user check the item. (All and not just the inline editing for certain row).